# Is casting an address of int whose value overflows a singed char to a pointer to char UB?

Tags: c++, casting

Hello I have this example:

```
int main(){

    int x = 300;
    char* p = (char*)&x;
    printf("%s\n", p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);

}
```

The output:

```
,
44
```

- Is it Undefined Behavior casting the address of `x` to `char*` as long as `x` has a positive value that overflows a `signed char`?
- Why I got this output? `,` and `44`? I've tried to understand so I thought `300 % 256 = 44` is converted and assigned to `p` so its character ASCII value is `,` on my implementation.

What do you think and recommend?

Comment: Whether it's UB, or not, does not depend on the value being pointed to. The cast itself will be either UB, or not. Then, dereferencing the resulting pointer will then either be UB, or not. There are two distinct steps here, and each one can be either UB, or not, on its own merits. Which step are you asking about?

Comment: Casting to `char*` is problematic when you write that to a stream, because it gets interpreted as C-style string. Casting to void is different, it is only interpreted as address when written to a stream. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I've edited it to using `printf` instead because it was really originally a C code not C++'s.

Comment: Using `%s` with `printf()` presents the same issues as streaming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no UB here. Generally, going such things violates strict aliasing (causing UB), but there is an exception allowing you to use `char` pointers to access any type.

`300` is represented in memory as 4 bytes: `44 1 0 0` (assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`, which is very common, and assuming little-endianness).

`printf("%s\n", p);` interprets those 4 bytes as a C-string. You would get the same result by printing

```
const char str[4] = {44, 1, 0, 0}; // Same as `{',', '\1', '\0', '\0'}`
```

In theory, you could get UB if the byte representation of `300` didn't contain null bytes, as it would cause `printf` to continue reading memory out of bounds of `x`, looking for a null-terminator. But there are no real platforms where that's the case, so it should be safe.

And `*p` accesses the first byte in the representation of `x`, which is `44`.

---

If you were to try this code on a big-endian platform, you would get an empty string and a `0` respectively, since the byte representation of `300` would be `0 0 1 44`.

---

> `x` has a positive value that overflows a `signed char`

This isn't a problem.

Answer (score 3):

> - Is it Undefined Behavior casting the address of `x` to `char*` as long as x has a positive value that overflows a signed char?

Regardless of the value of `x`, this is not undefined behaviour; you are allowed to do a `reinterpret_cast` from any pointer type to a `char*` pointer, as long as there are no issues with `const`.

Printing this value as a string **is** undefined behaviour, though: You may be on a system where `int` just uses 16 bit, so none of the bytes of the `int` accessible via the `char` pointer may be 0 result in a byte that is 0; `printf()` could therefore read past the memory guaranteed to be accessible.

> - Why I got this output? `,` and `44`? I've tried to understand so I thought `300 % 256 = 44` is converted and assigned to `p` so its character ASCII value is `,` on my implementation.

You're using a little-endian system using 32-bit `int`s. This means `300 = 0x12C` is seen as array `{ 0x2C, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00 }` (little-endian systems store the least significant byte first).

Now, trying to print this as a string, you get the first char with the value `0x2C`, i.e. the `','` character, followed by a non-printable character `0x01`. The following `0x00` char terminates the string, so the output seen is just `,`.

When printing the pointer value as a decimal, the only thing printed is `0x2C` in decimal base, i.e. `44`.